# Proving an inequality of roots to the nth degree

Tags: number-theory

Prove $\sqrt[7]{7!} < \sqrt[8]{8!}$

Initial thought: use a substitution where n=7 such that...

$(n!)^{1/n} < (n!(n+1))^{1/(n+1)} \rightarrow (n!)^{\frac{1}{(n(n+1))}} < (n!(n+1))^{\frac{1}{(n+1)}} $

I've tried a ton of different operations but I find myself going in a circle. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Hint: Take the $\log$ of both sides.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Raise the inequality to the $56$-th power and obtain

$$ (7!)^{8} < (8!)^7=(7!\cdot 8)^7\Leftrightarrow 7!<8^7 \Leftrightarrow 1\cdot2\cdot\cdots7<8\cdot 8\cdot\cdots8   $$